# How to open a locally saved PDF file with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, file

I've made a Swift menu bar app XCode 8.2.1. One of the menu bar options in this script successfully runs an AppleScript I created. I'd like to put another option in this menu bar app that opens a PDF instruction/read me file for the user. How do I open a locally saved PDF file in Swift?

I've included the code I have in the AppDelegate.swift file in XCode.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Layout Ad
//

import Cocoa


@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)

@IBAction func quitClicked(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
}


func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu

    let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
    //icon?.isTemplate = true // best for dark mode
    statusItem.image = icon
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    constructMenu()
}


func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


//Function to get the path to the applescript
func runApplescript(){
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
    task.arguments = ["/Library/Scripts/1_Page Layout Scripts/Layout Ad.scpt"]

    task.launch()
}

//Function to open the script's instructions
func openPDF(){
   //Code to open PDF file will go here
    //"/Volumes/NAS/Advertising Department/16_SCRIPTS/*Instructions/2_Running Scripts/1_InDesign/Layout Ad Script Instructions.pdf"
}


//Function to make the menu work
func constructMenu() {
    let menu = NSMenu()


    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Script Instructions", action: #selector(openPDF), keyEquivalent: ""))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Layout Ad", action: #selector(runApplescript), keyEquivalent: ""))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))

    statusItem.menu = menu
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSWorkspace` can do that.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Volumes/NAS/Advertising Department/16_SCRIPTS/*Instructions/2_Running Scripts/1_InDesign/Layout Ad Script Instructions.pdf")
NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
```